# Converting discretized integration into a continuous one

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

#### Summary and Question

I am trying to convert a discretized integration into a continuous one. Solving the integral requires information about $x$ which I do not have for the continuous integration. However, performing the discretized integration works as expected as concrete data points are evaluated beforehand.

Therefore, the question is: How can I convert the discretized integration into a continuous one? Which step or procedure am I missing?

#### Background Information

In chemical engineering, the *number of transfer units* $\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG}$ is defined as the following integral:

$$
\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG} = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^\mathrm{eq} - y} = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \frac{1}{y^\mathrm{eq} - y} \mathrm{d}y
$$

$y^\mathrm{eq}$ denotes the so-called *equilibrium curve* which, if $\alpha_\mathrm{12}$ is a constant, can be expressed as a function of $x$:

$$
y^\mathrm{eq} = \frac{\alpha_\mathrm{12} \cdot x}{1 + (\alpha_\mathrm{12} - 1) \cdot x}
$$

$y$ is given by the *operating line*. In the simplest case, the operating line is equivalent to the diagonal line and

$$
y = x
$$

can be used. Furthermore, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are points on the diagonal such that $y_1 = x_1$ and $y_2 = x_2$

Inserting the above definitions of $y^\mathrm{eq}$ and $y$ as well as the simplifications of $y_1 = x_1$ and $y_2 = x_2$ into $\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG}$ results in:

$$
\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG} = \int_{y_1=x_1}^{y_2=x_2} \frac{1}{\frac{\alpha_\mathrm{12} \cdot x}{1 + (\alpha_\mathrm{12} - 1) \cdot x} - x} \mathrm{d}y
$$

#### Discretized Integration

In most applications, the integral

$$
\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG} = \int_{y_1=x_1}^{y_2=x_2} \frac{1}{\frac{\alpha_\mathrm{12} \cdot x}{1 + (\alpha_\mathrm{12} - 1) \cdot x} - x} \mathrm{d}y
$$

is commonly evaluated with discrete values using the following procedure:

1. Define some $x$ values used for the evaluation.
2. Calculate $y^\mathrm{eq}$ values for the $x$ values defined in step 1 using the above equation.
3. Calculate $y$ values for the $x$ values defined in step 1 using the above equation.
4. Calculate $\Delta y = y^\mathrm{eq} - y$ based on the $y^\mathrm{eq}$ values and $y$ values from steps 2 and 3.
5. Calculate $(\Delta y)^{-1}$ (the reciprocals of the values calculated in step 4).
6. Integrate $(\Delta y)^{-1}$ with respect to $y$ using a discretized/numerical method (e.g. trapezoidal rule).

Using e.g. Python, the above steps can be performed as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

x_1 = 0.1
x_2 = 0.9
alpha_12 = 3

x = np.linspace(x_1, x_2)
y_eq = alpha_12 * x / (1 + (alpha_12 - 1) * x)
y = x
delta_y = y_eq - y
reciprocal = 1 / delta_y
ntu = np.trapz(reciprocal, y)

print(f'{ntu=}')
# --> 4.399
```

#### Graphical Interpretation

NTU can be interpreted graphically. The integral which defines NTU is represented by the gray area below the curve (exemplary illustration, curve is bent due to a more complex function for the operating line $y^\mathrm{b}$):

[image]

#### Continuous Integration

To prepare continuous integration, the antiderivative is derived:

$$
\mathrm{NTU}_\mathrm{oG}
= \int_{y_1=x_1}^{y_2=x_2} \frac{1}{\frac{\alpha_\mathrm{12} \cdot x}{1 + (\alpha_\mathrm{12} - 1) \cdot x} - x} \mathrm{d}y
= \frac{y}{\frac{x \cdot \alpha_\mathrm{12}}{( \alpha_\mathrm{12} - 1) \cdot x + 1} -x } \Big|_{x_1}^{x_2}
$$

As the integration is performed with respect to $y$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are inserted for $y$. However, I am unable to evaluate the according antiderivative since no values for $x$ are known in this procedure. What am I missing here? How can I convert the discretized integration described above into a continuous one?

*Remark: The problem described here certainly is an engineering problem which might be related to topics not suitable for math.stackexchange (see [Help Center > Asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). However, the underlying problem can be decoupled from any engineering motivation and reduced to a mathematical problem.*